# Implementing BST in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm trying to create a Binary Search Tree in C. This is how I've defined my `struct`

```
struct BSTNode {
  int value;
  struct BSTNode *left, *right;
}
```

I've created my root node at the top of my program like this

```
struct BSTNode *rootPtr = NULL;
```

I'm getting this error: "expected ';', identifier or '(' before 'struct'

How do I fix this? 
These are my packages, idk if it's relevant but yeah

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You need a `;` at the end of the `struct BSTNode` declaration.

Comment: This is just basic C syntax, nothing special about BST.

Comment: Oh wow. Thanks a lot haha :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add ; after the definition of the struct BSTnode.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).